# Trouble Configuring BGP on Cisco IOS-XE using Terraform

Tags: terraform, cisco, bgp

so I am struggling to do a PUT so I can configure a bgp asn on my Cisco catalyst 8000v deployed on AWS

```
provider "iosxe" {
  username = "ec2-user"
  password = "password"
  url      = "https://${aws_instance.Workload.public_ip}"
}

resource "iosxe_bgp" "BGP" {
  asn                  = "65000"
}

resource "iosxe_restconf" "BGP" {
  path = "Cisco-IOS-XE-native:native/bgp/"
}
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: This question really needs more context. What are you executing exactly? You mention a PUT, but that is something a terraform provider does for you in the back. What errors are you getting and what do you expect to see happen? Is this an existing resource by any chance that you want to start managing via terraform?

Comment: Hi Karl, you are correct, Terraform handles the PUT. The misunderstanding came from the vendors session I watched. The code works now, except that I removed the `iosxe_restconf` resource block.